# Affine transformation on a pixel grid

Tags: image-processing

I'm implementing affine transformations on images. Currently I'm doing rotation, but general transformation will be added later.

Basically each pixel is mapped by the rotation matrix R:

$\begin{bmatrix} cos(a) & -sin(a) \\ sin(a)  & cos(a) \end{bmatrix} $

The problem is that mapping back does not always come back to a grid point, so I basically rounding it using a brute force approach. What is a better approach (similarly to Bresenham's line drawing algorithm)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is an *interpolation method*.

The method you described is called nearest-neighbor, because you pick the pixel that is nearest to the place you actually wanted.

Other methods include:

- bi-linear interpolation (Select 4 nearest points, interpolate by `x` and `y` according to distance) (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation))
- barycentric interpolation (Select 3 nearest points, interpolate in the system of coordinates of the triangle)
- bi-cubic interpolation (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation))

Comment: Thanks! But are there any efficient implementation of this? This is a brute force approach and it's O(n^2), right?

Comment: @DzungNguyen, I am not sure what is `n` in your notation, but assuming that it is number of pixels, then no, it is a linear algorithm `O(n)`